# How to find all elements with class name containing a specific string using HTML-requests library?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors, python-requests-html

I am on this page on [Tokyo Olympic Website](https://olympics.com/tokyo-2020/olympic-games/en/results/all-sports/olympic-schedule-and-results-date=2021-07-24.htm)

I would like to get all the elements that has class name beginning with a specific string. For instance I want to get all elements that begin with 'col-sm-'.

`html.r.find('.col-sm-6')` gives me all elements that have class name col-sm-6. However I would like to get all elements starting with class name col-sm-. In documentation they have asked to refer CSS selector [at this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). As per the information on that page either:

`r.html.find('[class~=col-sm-]')` or
`r.html.find('[class=col-sm-]')` should do the job but they return an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that would work

```
*[class^='col-sm-']
```

Here is an image from chropath extension

[image: As you can see, other classes that starts with col-sm- are returned as well]